# select2 option cannot display selected value with axios query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-select2

I have project with reactjs and select. And on this project, i using axios instead of ajax default select2.

Init select2 code :

```
$(selector).select2({
         placeholder: placeholder,
         query: function (options) {
           // Membuat permintaan Axios secara manual
           axios.get(`${api_uri}/${endpoint}`, {
             params: {
               q: options.term,
             },
             withCredentials: true,
           })
             .then(function (response) {
               // Mengonversi respons ke format yang diharapkan oleh Select2
               var results = $.map(response.data.data.result, function (item) {
                 return {
                  id: item._id,
                  text: item.nama
                 };
               });
       
               // Memanggil fungsi callback success dengan hasil permintaan
               console.log(results);
               options.callback({ results: results });
             })
             .catch(function (error) {
               // Memanggil fungsi callback error jika terjadi kesalahan
               options.callback({ results: [], more: false, errors: [error] });
             });
         },
         processResults: function (data) {
            return {
               results: data.results,
            };
         }
      });
```

Its showing all of options, but when i click on the options its not selected